# Splitting a method into multiple

Tags: java, android

When the method is single, it works fine.

```
String as = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
products.add("Banana" +as+ "Its color is yellow.");
products.add("Orange" +as+ "Orange is a sour fruit.");
products.add("Onion" +as+ "Onion usually used on Pizza");
```

If it's splitted into multiple; it does not work.

```
String as = System.getProperty("line.separator");

ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
    addFirstThousand(products);
    addSecondThousand(products);

    private void addFirstThousand(ArrayList<String> products) {
        products.add("Banana" +as+ "Its color is yellow.");
        products.add("Orange" +as+ "Orange is a sour fruit.");
        products.add("Onion" +as+ "Onion usually used on Pizza");
        }

    private void addSecondThousand(ArrayList<String> products) {
    products.add("Apple" +as+ "Apple is a big corporation");
    products.add("Love" +as+ "Love is releted to heart");
    products.add("Pizza" +as+ "It's origineted from Italy");

    }
```

For easier understinding:

[image]

How can I split this in multiple?

Comment: Should be fine... Here's a small test case to reproduce what *should* work: http://ideone.com/zvEunK ... Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that others can run to test your issue?

Comment: What are the compiler errors?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call a method from within the class code itself. You cannot do this (except in static initialization blocks, which won't work in this case).

Depending on where you're working, the following code needs to be moved:

```
addFirstThousand(products);
addSecondThousand(products);
```

- If you're working in an `Activity`, this code should be in `onCreate()`;
- For a `Fragment`, use `onViewCreated()`;
- For just about anything else use the constructor.

The remainder should stay how it is.

Something like this (for an `Activity`):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    String as = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addFirstThousand(products);
        addSecondThousand(products);
    }

    private void addFirstThousand(ArrayList<String> products) {
        products.add("Banana" +as+ "Its color is yellow.");
        products.add("Orange" +as+ "Orange is a sour fruit.");
        products.add("Onion" +as+ "Onion usually used on Pizza");
    }

    private void addSecondThousand(ArrayList<String> products) {
        products.add("Apple" +as+ "Apple is a big corporation");
        products.add("Love" +as+ "Love is releted to heart");
        products.add("Pizza" +as+ "It's origineted from Italy");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not yet getting rid of the problem! Image link https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/pb-2.png

Comment: No, no, you have to close the `onCreate()` method. Take a look again at the example I've placed above, and compare it to yours. (Note the `}` above `private void addFirstThousand`.)

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess at an answer without the exact compiler errors. My guess is that you have declared the `addFirstThousand()` and `addSecondThousand()` methods inside of another method. Java does not allow this. If this is the case, then you can fix the problem by moving these methods outside of the containing method. They should be declared inside a *class* but not inside other methods.

Answer (score 0):

There can be reasons..

1. You are calling `addFirstThousand(products);` and 
   `addSecondThousand(products);` these methods from a static method.
   **solution**: make `addFirstThousand(products);` and 
   `addSecondThousand(products);` to static **or** call these method using
   create object.
2. You are calling `addFirstThousand(products);` and `addSecondThousand(products);` these methods from different class.
   **solution**: call these method using create object.